# using python 2.3 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-10.04

i need to run some old python programs on a ubuntu 10.04 system. it seems, that there are no python 2.3 packages for ubuntu 10.04 available. so i got python 2.3 directly from python.org: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/

but "make" python fails with a buffer overflow.

has anyone suggestions how to get python 2.3 to work on ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what python programs require **no greater than 2.3**?

Comment: it is about **compiled** python2.3 files, that are executed on older hardware. new hardware with ubuntu 10.04 has been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an old bug in Python 2.3.  From here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/286334

The solution is to run configure with BASECFLAGS=-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE.

```
./configure BASECFLAGS=-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
```

Then run make as you usually would.

Comment: Yes! That did it. Just had to clean previously used working directory, ran the stated, flaged configure cmd and ran the usual make and make install. Thanks a lot. I am regularly amazed by the speed of stackoverflow and its users.

Answer (score 0):

You could [decompile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/) your python compiled files back to source. That way they will work in any python version up to 2.7+, probably unchanged.