# Install Python 2.3 or earlier on a Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: python, macos

I have Mac OS X 10.7.5 and would like to install < = python 2.3 on it.

I need it as one of the s/w I would like to try is based on an older version and does not seem to work with the new ones.
I am not sure if the s/w is wrong (doesn't seem like it) or is it really the python version that is messing it up.

I tried 2.4 (using mac ports) but thats not it so I want to go further back but I cannot do it with fink or mac ports.

Any other suggestions ? I tried to install using a tar file but that gave errors.

Comment: python2.3 is pretty old... You might be out of luck on this one...  I don't know what a "s/w" is, but it might be easier to update it to work with python2.7 or whatever OS-X is installing by default these days.

Comment: It's also possible that Python 2.3 would not help (e.g. the software may be relying on old system calls, in which case the problem is not Python but OS/X).  If you give the kind of errors you get, people here would be able to help you port or fix the software.

Comment: What Armin said. Something that relies on 2.3 is likely very old and OS X has changed a lot since then.  Plus there are lots of other reasons why it may not work, including installation issues.  You need to supply more information about exactly what you are trying to install and what errors you are seeing.  Trying to install 2.3 is almost certainly not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with migilson about being out of luck on a native OSX solution.  If you did manage to install, it could be quite troublesome if it's done outside of a fink / mac ports/ homebrew solution.  Note that homebrew does not have a formula for Python2.3 either.

Probably a far from ideal solution would be to create a Linux virtual machine that supports Python 2.3.  However, this would give you the Python version as well as a 100% safe sandbox to play in.  A few quick searches looks like Fedora has an RPM for Python2.3.  Ubuntu (my recommendation) also looks like you can build Python2.3 from source [see here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934925/using-python-2-3-on-ubuntu-10-04).

Quick References

- [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org)
- [Fedora Python2.3 RPM](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3.3/rpms/)
- [Ubuntu 10.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/)